# Connection string outside the code

Tags: database, connection-string

Im doing a C# Application with 2 Windows Forms and a Database Connection. The connection String to that Database is referenced on the code, but i dont want it to.

I want to know how to keep that Connection String outside of my code, so if something has to change, that change only happens outside the program.

Hope i made myself clear.

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: what about putting the code in the `App,config` file? Or do you want it further away from the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your connection strings using App.config.  If you need to recall user credentials, be sure to encrypt the connection string as outlined in the article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1

Just go to the "Properties" node then double-click on "Settings.Settings". You will then get a grid with columns for Name, Type, Scope and Value as in the following:
```

[image]
    Step 2

```
Now, specify a name, then click in the Type cell. In the drop-down box choose "Connection String". Then set the Scope to "Application".
```

[image]

```
Step 3

Then click in the value cell and an ellipsis ("...") will appear in the right. Click on the ellipsis and create the connection string.
```

[image]
    Then in the program, access (use) the connection string using: Properties.Setting.Default.(name) where (name) is the name you provided in the name column.

```
Example

In this example, we will display a record in a DataGridView on a button click.

Coding

Form1.cs[Design]
```

[image]

```
Form1.cs

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

App.config

You see that the Connection String is automatically included..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString.Properties.Settings.connection" connectionString="Data Source=MCNDESKTOP43;Initial Catalog=EmpDetail;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>


Output

[![enter image description here][5]][5]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyNXF.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BJ5a.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ViL.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGC5a.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZO22.jpg
```

Comment: Ref :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/create-single-connection-string-for-all-windows-form-in-net/